# Is it possible to embed Sublime Text in my application as text editor?

Tags: mfc, sublimetext2

My application was developed in MFC and used CRichEditCtrl as text editor.

I found sublime text has lots of amazing features like multiple cursor.

Is it possible to embed Sublime Text in my application to replace the CRichEditCtrl?

Could anyone point me a direction so I can start?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had a quick look at the Sublime website and I doubt it is possible. Best people to ask would be the author(s).

Comment: I've never seen it used like this. I don't think this possibility is offered.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. There could be a chance if Sublime Text was open source. But it's not, and you won't be able to create a control based off of it. However, you can always try developing your own. I'm not sure what version you're using, but this might help get you started: [Creating and Using Custom Controls in VC++ - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5032/Creating-and-Using-custom-controls-in-VC)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've create I project I call [pyblime](https://github.com/brupelo/pyblime), it's exactly what you're asking for but intended to be used with python&qt. In any case, I post it here so it can give some ideas how you could start tackling this problem.